# Items in Arrays, are they references?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

look at the code below:

```
$index = GetIndexForId($itemid);

$item = null;

if( $index == -1 )
{
    $item = array();
    $this->items[] = $item;
    $index = count($this->items)-1;
}
else
    $item = $this->items[$index];

$item['id'] = $itemid;
$item['qty'] = $qty;
$item['options'] = $options;

$this->items[$index] = $item; // This line is my question
```

The last line, is it necessary? I really dont know how php handles array assignment.

P.S. GetIndexForId just searches for if the current ID already exists in the array, and the other "undeclared" variables are parameters.

Comment: I love getting -1's from a question I posted 3.5 years ago. To whoever you are, please leave a comment as to why?!?!?!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Any value type like boolean, int... will not be passed by reference. But if your array is filled with objects, it WILL be passed by reference. In your exemple, you need the last line. But as I said, if $item were an object you wouldn't need the last line. It is possible to pass a value type by reference with the reference operator.

Learn how to use the reference operator
[HERE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)

Comment: do arrays count as "objects" in php? (im used to C#) and each "item" is defined as an array...

Comment: No. Unlike most OOP languages where everything is an object, in PHP, only explicit objects are considered "objects".

Comment: No, there is no difference between how things of different types are stored in arrays. Everything is stored by value, unless you explicitly specify `&`, in which case it will be by reference. "Objects" are not values in PHP 5. What you have are object references. They are stored by value if there is no `&`.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> Array assignment always involves value copying. Use the reference operator to copy an array by reference.

So yes, given your code, the last line is necessary, but `$this->items[] = $item;` is superfluous.

Comment: can you add an item by index and have the array's "key" updated properly?

Comment: @TJMonk15: I don't really understand what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update your Object, yes you need this last line

Comment: $index = count($this->items)-1; handles the problem you pose, but ty

Comment: what do you mean ? If you want to update `$this->items[$index]` with the changes you've made to `$item`, then you need the last line to update `$this->items[$index]`

Comment: ok, thats what i thought, but you said [something you removed] and i dont remember exactly what it was.

Comment: yeah I was trying to explain what I say in my last comment but it wasn't clear :D